# What is the difference between Tesla, Tipsy and Validus builds?

Tags: custom-roms

I want to flash Validus ROM on my OnePlus One. I looked up at the website of [Validus ROM](http://validusrom.com/) and they have not mentioned the difference between those three builds. When I checked some XDA threads I found that at least Tipsy and Validus builds  seem to have **Status: Stable**.

So what is the idea behind the naming scheme? They don't seem to be like nightly, milestone and stable which CM follows.

I want to download and flash a build but I'm confused which one to download.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is in the project they are based on (i.e., their parent ROM).

Validus is based on CyanogenMod, Tesla is based on Slim(Kat/LP), Tipsy is based mostly Android Open Source Project (AOSP) with some Slim(Kat/LP).

Comment: Could you please add some citations to verify your claim?

Comment: I originally gleaned this from google+, but can't find the reference, but here is the same info in a [post from xda developers forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=63335915&postcount=232)

Answer (score 1):

- Tipsy is Slim base with full OMS support. It is still WIP. No build rolling yet
- Tesla is GZ-AOSP (Fancy name of AOSP-CAF?) base with full OMS support and has handpicked useful features.
- Validus is GZ-AOSP based too with a dark wolfie theme with full OMS support too and have a lot of features.

REF:https://forum.xda-developers.com/mi-max/development/gzr-team-tipsy-tesla-validus-t3526087